# Problem with docker network and /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: debian, networking, docker, docker-compose

***First case:***

I have the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}project.api
    ports:
      - "5080:5080"
      - "5081:5081"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Api/Dockerfile.Debug
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5080;http://+:5081;http://+:5443
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=5080
      - MANAGEMENT_HTTP_PORT=5081
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
```

When doing `docker-compose up` the container cannot access some endpoint that is supposed to give a token to the api running in the container. So I am having a timeout error.

***Second case:***
However, with the following file it works with no problem.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}project.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Api/Dockerfile.Debug
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5080;http://+:5081;http://+:5443
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=5080
      - MANAGEMENT_HTTP_PORT=5081
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
    network_mode: host
```

It's worth noticing that on my host machine, the token-endpoint is accessible only when my vpn is running.

I've tried to to see what's is the `/etc/resolv.conf/` in the containers in both cases (using `docker exec -it "container_id" bash`):

***First Case: (the non-working case)***

```
search XXX.biz YYY.biz
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

***Second Case: (the working case)***

```
search XXX.biz  YYY.biz
nameserver 10.10.***.***
nameserver 10.11.***.***
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I tried to add the missing entries
nameserver 10.10.***.***
nameserver 10.11.***.***
nameserver 8.8.8.8

in `daemon.json` as following:

```json
{
    "dns": [ "10.10.***.***", "10.11.***.***", "8.8.8.8" ],
    "dns-search": [ "XXX.biz", "YYY.biz" ]
}
```

but it doesn't solve the problem with the first case and I still don't see those entries inside the `/etc/resolve.conf/` file inside my container.

Any ideas how to fix the first case?

PS: I have a debian 10 machine

I have tried all of the following attempts, nothing works

***Attempt 1:*** I also tried to add `dns` entries in docker-compose file but it doesn't work neither.

***Attempt 2:*** Adding dns entries in docker-compose and also `networ_mode : brdige`.
This  also adds the entries in the `/etc/resolv.conf` but the app still cannot get the token.

***Attempt 3:*** Manual mounting where ./resolv.conf file contains what is expected.

```
volumes:
- ./resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf
```

This  also adds the entries in the `/etc/resolv.conf` but the app still cannot get the token.

The error is

```
An error has occurred in Timed KeyCloak Authentificated Service
api_1  |       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (oauth2.XXX.com:443)
```

The problem seems to be related to accessing the internet generally and not just accessing the token provider. Indeed, executing the following script within the container returns "Offline"

```bash
echo -e "GET http://google.com HTTP/1.0\n\n" | nc google.com 80 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Online"
else
    echo "Offline"
fi
Offline
```

Comment: Hi probably the easiest way is to use a fixed resolv.conf use as a volume to overwrite the internal resolv.conf ie : -v ./resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf